# How to get element by both id and class

Tags: javascript, html, class, dom

Is there any alternative solution (in JavaScript) for `document.getElementById();` to select a specific element, specifying both the class and id ?

for example I have such a content:

```
<a class="q_href" onclick="showQuestion(1)">Question 1:</a>
<div class="q_content" id="1"></div>

<a class="q_href" onclick="showQuestion(2)">Question 2:</a>
<div class="q_content" id="2"></div>
```

And I want to select the corresponding div under the "Question X" link in the function

```
function showQuestion(id)
{
var thediv = GetByClassAndId("q_content",id); // how to implement this function ?
WriteQuestionIn(thediv); //Ajax
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? Given that id should be unique it is enough on its own to select an element. Unless the idea is to select it if and only if it also has the specified class? In which case `document.querySelectorAll("#id.class")` should do it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  The Id by itself is enough...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since ID is always unique (unless u make a mistake) u have no need to use both class and id to select the element.
Such an approach is not correct, and should be **avoided at all cost**.

What I suspect is your problem, is that the ID is only a number. Try adding a prefix which is a letter. Do view source to this page to see examples.

```
<a class="q_href" onclick="showQuestion(1)">Question 1:</a>
<div class="q_content" id="q1"></div>

<a class="q_href" onclick="showQuestion(2)">Question 2:</a>
<div class="q_content" id="q2"></div>

function showQuestion(id)
{
var thediv = document.getElementById("q"+id);
WriteQuestionIn(thediv); //Ajax
}
```

Comment: I didn't know id should be unique. And that's why I asked this, in case there are other elements with id="1". But you are right, an id like "qcontent_1" would be better. Thanks !

Comment: id must be unique in a page, yes. Otherwise unexpected things can happen if u have complex JS/css involved with this element

Answer (score 13):

you can try `document.querySelector()`

like `document.querySelector(".q_content#2")` use the para like css selector..

Comment: u see that the `.q_content#2` and `#2` suppose to be the same, right?

Comment: right.. That's same. I approve your answer. But if he realy want to do that, he can use this...

Comment: i misunderstood his qustion.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is a function `$` in jQuery for doing this operation. If you are using any framework, then you should remember there is always a jQuery library available. Else if you are using custom PHP, then add one of them like jQuery or other because they provide lots of types of selectors.

Now here is the code after adding jQuery:

```js
$("#yourid") //basic selector
$("#yourid.yourclass").show()
```

Use `.show()` to show the selected element

Use `.hide()` To hide element